# Run js 1.6 seconds after last key up

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I run some js 1.6 after a keyup, but if a keyup happens within the 1.6 seconds, it cancels and starts waiting another 1.6 seconds.

Here is how I can think of doing it:

```
var waiting = false;
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function(){
    waiting = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(!timerRunning){
            //js here
        }
    }, 1600);
});
```

Is there a better way to approach this then what I have mentioned above?

Comment: Assign your `setTimeout` to a variable. On keydown, clear the `setTimeout` using (`clearTimeout`). It'll be re-assigned on keyup.

Answer (score 1):

using `clearTimeout` is probably a more elegant solution

```
var timer;
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function(){
    if(!timer)
        clearTimeout(timer);
    timer=setTimeout(function(){
        //js here
    },1600);
});
```

Comment: when is `timer` being assigned? If it is not assigned, why clear it?

Comment: You forgot to assign the result of `setTimeout` here to `timer`. Also `timer!=null` is kind of clunky, as `if (timer)` would do the job. It starts out as `undefined` anyway.

Comment: Yes, the setTimeout has to be assigned to timer.

Comment: yeah, seems pretty important. Weird that your edits got rejected, I'll edit it myself